# Why is the atos command unable to find symbols for my iOS crash log?

Tags: iphone, ios, macos, terminal

I'm trying to diagnose a crash of my iOS application.  Others here have suggested the use of the `atos` command to do this, like in the following commands:

```
atos -arch armv7 -o ''/'appname.app.dSYM'
symbolicatecrash "appname_2011-08-03-111047_Test-iPhone.crash" "apname.app"
```

When I attempt this, however, the command fails with the error

> atos cannot load symbols for the file

What could be causing this error, and how can I fix this?  Also, is this the proper way to determine the memory location of a crash within an iOS application from a crash log?

Comment: Did you use Xcode "Archive" option to deploy your app? If so, you can just drop .crash file into "device log" section of Xcode organizer.

Comment: Will that give the exact line and method Evgeniy? I think not, and Rizwan might want to know that information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dSYM file/dir must be the **exact** same one that was created when you built your submitted app-store build. Even another one built from the exact same code-base won't match against your crash-log.

Some potential causes:

- You built and tested your app and once you decided it was fine you saved the binaries (.app and .dSYM), then you rebuilt with appstore signing and forgot to archive THAT version of of the .app and .dSYM. Now your archived version won't match with crashes form the appstore version.
- You are trying to symbolicate using a freshly-built .app and .dSYM from source-control. You need to use the same .app and .dSYM that were submitted.

If you do have the correct dSYM anywhere on your computer (and the correct iOS debug info installed) then Xcode will automatically find it and create a symbolicated copy of the crash-log when you import the crash-log. It does this using spotlight to find a unique string that's generated at build time (this is why the exact version is needed for it to match). Note that the matching .app file also needs to be present.

Best practice is to build and test a release version, then re-sign it for submission (rather than submitting a separate build for app-store signing). This way you can preserve the correct .app and .dSYM somewhere safe. I put them in source control and tag it with the release number.

Comment: Note: I edited out some parts of my original answer that were wrong - AppLoader doesn't re-sign your binaries, you need to do it yourself. The app-store previously accepted Enterprise-signed apps with a matching company-name which made me think it was re-signing when it wasn't.

Comment: Great tip @jhabbott, regarding the re-signing of the build. I think i am caught in that process right now. I am able to get around my situation but clearly yes, your first bulleted point is bang-on.